# React | props inside UseCallBack not updating inside custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, usecallback

I've build an custom custom post hook that returns the API response and the API post. And I am using `useCallback` hook to set the `Response state`

**Where it goes wrong** is that the `Package prop` doesn't update inside the `useCallback` hook.

When I log `Package` outside the `useCallback` hook I get the right data inside the propertie. However when I log the `Package prop` inside the `useCallback` hook the value of `Package` doesn't change.

*No matter how many times I press the button*

**I've tried** creating an order `state` that updates everytime the `Package prop` updates, however whenever I set `Package` as an value in the `scope` I get an infinite loop.

I've alos added `Package` into the `scope` of the `useCallback` hook

**example**

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setOrder(Package);
  }, [Package]);
```

**What I expect to happen is** that whenever I call my custom `usePostOrder` hook the value of `Package` that is inside the `useCallback` is always up to date with the latest passed on prop.

**CustomHook**

```
/**
 * custom post hook that returns the API response and the API post function
 * @param {string} url
 * @param {object} Package
 * @returns {array} and @param {function}
 */

export const usePostOrder = (url, Package) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [order, setOrder] = React.useState(Package);
  const [response, setResponse] = React.useState({
    config: {
      data: []
    },
    data: {
      id: 0
    }
  });

  console.log("outside func", Package);
  const postOrder = React.useCallback(async () => {
    console.log("inside func", Package);
  }, [url, loading, Package]);

  return [response, postOrder];
};
```

**Answer by Jake Luby**
*with a slight adjustment*

```
/**
 * custom post hook that returns the API response and the API post function
 * @param {string} url
 * @param {object} Package
 * @returns {array} and @param {function}
 */

export const usePostOrder = (url, Package, send) => {
  const [postOrder, setPostOrder] = React.useState();
  const [response, setResponse] = React.useState({
    config: {
      data: []
    },
    data: {
      id: 0
    }
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async send => {
      //this will have the updated input Package
      await axios
        .post(ApiUrl + url, Package)
        .then(function(response) {
          setResponse(response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          setResponse(error);
          console.log(error);
        });
    };

    send && getData();
  }, [send]); //this will run when url or Package changes

  return [response, postOrder];
};

useAsyncEndpoint.PropTypes = {
  url: PropTypes.url,
  user: PropTypes.object,
  club: PropTypes.object,
  cartItems: PropTypes.array
};
```

How I call this hook

```
import {usePostOrder} from "./yourHooksFolder"
  const [send, setSend] = React.useState(false);
  const [response, postOrder] = usePostOrder(
    "url",
    createOrder(user, store, cartItems),
    send
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setSend(false);
  }, [response]);

// send order
  const onGoToPaymentPressed = () => {
    setSend(true);
  };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`useCallback` is not meant to be used like that.  It doesn't actually run the function, it simply memoizes it so that between renders the same function isn't recreated.

What you want is the `useEffect` hook and to have the postOrder as part of the state:

```
export const usePostOrder = (url, Package) => {
  const [postOrder, setPostOrder] = React.useState()
  const [response, setResponse] = React.useState({
    config: {
      data: []
    },
    data: {
      id: 0
    }
  })


  React.useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async url => {
        //this will have the updated input Package
        console.log(Package) 

        //here is where you'll have your REST calls

        //set your data which will then update the return values in the hook and cause a rerender
        setPostOrder(returnValue)
        setResponse(someResponse)
    }

    getData()
  }, [url, Package]) //this will run when url or Package changes

  return [response, postOrder]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've also decided to pass on a `send` `prop` that's a boolean. If this value is true then it will execute the `getData()` function. 
Preventing unnecessary requests. Would you recommend this?

Comment: No, I’d recommend using useEffect as it does what you want out of the box without extra listeners